PostgreSql Row-Level Locks
I am trying to understand Postgresql Row-Level Locks could someone help me understand when to use each type of lock.
     FOR UPDATE; FOR NO KEY UPDATE; FOR SHARE; FOR KEY SHARE;

I tried to go over the documentation but still, I couldn't understand the difference and didn't know when to use what and how does it make a difference.
I am expecting someone could help me understand the use case of each lock and give me clarity on when to choose each.

This only states you don't understand something and you expect someone to come and change that. You need to ask a specific question. This table in the doc should be all you need: locks are there so that one thing can block another whenever you're afraid the two things shouldn't happen concurrently. Consider what concurrent actions on the row could break your code and pick the lock type that will prevent/block/stop those until your code is done.

The most common lock type you will use is FOR UPDATE. The other ones can be useful in more "exotic" scenarios, that you probably won't encounter often.

What problem do you have? Why are you looking at these locks in the first place?

I am learning about postgres sql Locks @FrankHeikens


lock a row in FOR UPDATE mode if you plan to delete it or to update a column that belongs to a primary key or unique constraint

lock a row in FOR NO KEY UPDATE mode if you plan to update only columns that do not belong to a primary key or unique constraint

lock a row in FOR SHARE mode if you don't want anybody else to modify it (a very rare requirement)

lock a row in FOR KEY SHARE mode if you want to keep anybody else from deleting the row or updating a column that belongs to a primary key or unique constraint (also a very rare requirement)


It is difficult to come up with a use case that requires you to use FOR SHARE and FOR KEY SHARE explicitly; they are taken be the database internally to make sure that foreign key constraints are not violated.
